# React Native unable to update view

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm new to react native.

Inside my `componentDidMount()` method I have two fetch request.
Each fetch request will give a `json` response. I want to update the view with the new `json` response.

I tried but I'm continuously getting the error:

> ```
> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'allRowIDs.length')
> ListView_render
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Lists\ListView\ListView.js:391:52
> <unknown>
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1231:14
> measureLifeCyclePerf
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:63:11
> _renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1231:8
> _renderValidatedComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1262:26
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:517:24
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> mountChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactMultiChild.js:280:10
> initializeChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:68:41
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:174:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:534:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> mountChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactMultiChild.js:280:10
> initializeChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:68:41
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:174:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:534:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> mountChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactMultiChild.js:280:10
> initializeChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:68:41
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:174:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:534:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:534:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> mountChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactMultiChild.js:280:10
> initializeChildren
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:68:41
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeBaseComponent.js:174:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:534:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> performInitialMount
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:534:6
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:365:8
> mountComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:57:6
> _updateRenderedComponentWithNextElement
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1178:8
> _updateRenderedComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1124:6
> _performComponentUpdate
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:1055:36
> updateComponent
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:940:8
> performUpdateIfNecessary
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:794:8
> performUpdateIfNecessary
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactReconciler.js:210:46
> runBatchedUpdates
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdates.js:146:6
> perform
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:152:24
> perform
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:152:24
> perform
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdates.js:78:6
> flushBatchedUpdates
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdates.js:164:24
> closeAll
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:223:29
> perform
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:165:24
> batchedUpdates
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:61:33
> enqueueUpdate
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdates.js:183:36
> enqueueUpdate
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdateQueue.js:33:29
> enqueueSetState
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdateQueue.js:246:18
> setState
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:167:31
> <unknown>
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\app\dashboardComponent\TicketDetails.js:60:22
> tryCallOne
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14
> <unknown>
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25
> <unknown>
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:117:50
> callTimer
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimersExecution.js:95:8
> callImmediatesPass
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimersExecution.js:199:36
> callImmediates
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimersExecution.js:214:11
> <unknown>
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:223:23
> __guard
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:213:6
> __callImmediates
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:223:17
> <unknown>
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:102:6
> __guard
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:213:6
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>     D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:100:17
> ```

**Here is my code**

```
const SideMenu = require('react-native-side-menu');
const Menu = require('./Menu');
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ListView, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Navigator } from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components'
import authController from '../authController/auth'
import frequentData from '../frequentData/frequentData'
import cannedResponseController from '../cannedResponseComponent/cannedResponse'
const platForm = require('react-native').Platform.OS;

export default class TicketDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {data : [], isLoading: true, tikid : '113',
       isOpen: false,
      selectedItem: 'About',};
  }

  toggle() {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
      });
    }

    updateMenuState(isOpen) {
      this.setState({ isOpen, });
    }

    onMenuItemSelected = (item) => {
      frequentData.setSelectedItem(item);

      this.setState({
        isOpen: false,
        selectedItem: item,
      });

      const refernce = this;
      refernce.navigate('tickets');
      console.log("Selected Item : "+ item);
    }

  componentDidMount() {


    // get Ticket details
    console.log("Ticket Details for Ticket Id : "+ frequentData.getSelectedticketId().toString());
      return fetch('https://user-api.zupportdesk.com/api/Ticket/GetTicket?TicketID='+ frequentData.getSelectedticketId().toString(), {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                  'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ frequentData.thirdjsoncalltoken,
              },
       })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log("Tick id to Display : "+ responseJson.ReturnObj.TicketID);
          this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          tikid : responseJson.ReturnObj.TicketID,
          dataSource:'nodata',
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });



      console.log("Selected Ticket id to get data : "+ frequentData.getSelectedticketId().toString());
        return fetch('https://user-api.zupportdesk.com/api/Ticket/GetTicketHistory?TicketID='+ frequentData.getSelectedticketId().toString(), {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ frequentData.thirdjsoncalltoken,
                },
         })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
          }, function() {
            // do something with new state
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });


    }




  navigate(routeName) {
    this.props.navigator.push({ name : routeName });
  }

  render() {
      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      }

      const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} />;
      return (
        <SideMenu
                menu={menu}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                onChange={(isOpen) => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}>
                <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text>TicketID tt : {this.state.tikid} </Text>

                <ListView
                      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                      renderRow={(rowData) =>
                        <View style={{marginTop: 10}} >
                        <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >Ticket History</Text>
                          <Image style={{height: 50, width: 50} } source={ require('../assests/companyIcon.png') } />
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >MailSubject : {rowData.MailSubject}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >TicketID : {rowData.TicketID}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >SendTo : {rowData.SendTo}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >Body : {rowData.Body}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >CompanyID : {rowData.CompanyID}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >QueueDate : {rowData.QueueDate}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >AttacmentIDsString : {rowData.AttacmentIDsString}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >AttacmentNamesString : {rowData.AttacmentNamesString}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >AgentProfileToken : {rowData.AgentProfileToken}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >CreatedUserEmail : {rowData.CreatedUserEmail}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >BadgeType : {rowData.BadgeType}</Text>
                          <Text style={{marginTop: 3}} >CreatedUserName : {rowData.CreatedUserName}</Text>
                        </View>
                      }
                    />

                </View>
                <Button style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.toggle()}>
                  <Image
                    source={require('./menu.png')} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
                </Button>
              </SideMenu>

      );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex : 1,
    flexDirection : 'column',
    //justifyContent: 'center',
    //alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor : '#F3F3F4',
  }
  ,navMenuBtn : {

  }
  ,navMenuIcon : {
      height : 50,
      width : 30,
      marginLeft : 15
  }


});


class Button extends Component {
  handlePress(e) {
    if (this.props.onPress) {
      this.props.onPress(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}
        style={this.props.style}>
        <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('ticketApp12', () => ticketApp12);
```

Can someone help me to fix this thanks.

Comment: can you please ellaborate and i couldnt find allRowIDs in the snipper provided.

Comment: Add your full stack trace. If it's a compile error, you can see the file name & error line in error console. Are you debugging?

Comment: @AjithPandian i updated the question. please check.

Comment: `D:\MobileApps\ticketApp12\app\dashboardComponent\TicketDetails.js:60:22` - can you leave a comment in the snippet where line 60 of TicketDetails.js is?

Comment: I think the problem in this line. 'tikid : responseJson.ReturnObj.TicketID'. Log responseJson and check whether you get correct response. Can you provide your response sample?

Comment: @SathyaBaman Why do you return `fetch`?